# API in SLIM framework returns invalid "l" before JSON

Tags: json, slim

I'm currently using SLIM as an API framework to return some values from a Mysql database via JSON.  Using PDO:

```
// PDO database library
$container['db'] = function ($c) {
    $settings = $c->get('settings')['db'];
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $settings['host'] . ";dbname=" . $settings['dbname'],
        $settings['user'], $settings['pass']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $pdo;
};
```

my json all returns good except before the return I get this character "l".
This is `"l[{"id":"4523","order_date":"2017-04-12""`...
That is just part of the response the rest is valid json.  The problem is the "l" which is at the beginning.  All my results have this.

Here is also one of the routes

```
// get orders
    $app->get('/orders', function ($request, $response, $args) {
         $sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT dr_orderss.id, dr_orderss.order_date, dr_orderss.inspection_date, dr_orderss.inspection_time, dr_orderss.inspector_id,
inspector.name AS inspector, dr_orderss.address, dr_orderss.city
FROM
dr_orderss
INNER JOIN dr_persons AS inspector ON
dr_orderss.inspector_id = inspector.id
GROUP BY dr_orderss.id
ORDER BY dr_orderss.inspection_date DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10");
        $sth->execute();
        $orders = $sth->fetchAll();
        return $this->response->withJson($orders);
    });
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please share one of the routes as well.

Comment: @Jeremy Kendall  I just edited the message to add a route.

Comment: There's nothing that jumps out to me as the problem, and unless I'm badly mistaken the code you've shared is fine. Time to start the process of elimination. If an empty route causes the same output, there's probably something silly like a stray "l" somewhere in your code that's being output to the screen. I've made mistakes like that more than once :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `1` just before a `<?php` tag in one of your files.